# conv_integer in vhdl

Tags: vhdl

Does this look right?

`Lookup_table(conv_integer(128 - Position));` --Position is `std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)`

The reference page for the function `conv_integer` doesn't say if one can have two arguments operating in between the parenthesis as above. It does however return an integer if the argument is an integer. Any thoughts?

Comment: So you're trying to convert to integer a `std_logic_vector(127 downto 0)`? Am I understanding this question correctly?

Comment: No. 128 is an integer, and "position" is a type std_logic_vector of bit length 8 bits. I am trying to subtract the integer value of "position" from 128 and use the integer result to index data in an array LUT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `to_integer` method.

You can do int math to your position by converting it to an integer using one of the following lines of code:

`to_integer(unsigned(Position))` or `to_integer(signed(Position))` depending on whether or not  it's a signed or unsigned 8 bit vector.

You can then do `Lookup_table(128 - to_integer(unsigned(Position)))`.

You should always do a specific `signed`/`unsigned` cast before converting to integer from a lower order (less bits) logic vector. Additionally, if you're doing `int` math it's good practice to convert to integer before doing the arithmetic.

Otherwise, VHDL is like any regular programming language in that it will evaluate a method's arguments before putting them into a method, so having an operation being performed inside the argument is perfectly fine.

Comment: Should you specify "unsigned" even if the type is std_logic_vector and not unsigned? What could go wrong mathematically with the way I have it right now? It compiles fine.

Comment: it's either a "signed" logic vector or an "unsigned" logic vector. for example if your std logic vector's constants were x"FF" should that go to -1 or 127?

Answer (score 0):

For VHDL, I usually use 1 of 2 method for convert between std_logic_vector and integer.

1. Use std_logic_unsigned/std_logic_signed library: for this method, Simulator/Synthesis tool auto infer your std_logic_vector to signed or unsigned.
2. Use numeric_std library: for this one, I use unsigned/signed to convert std_logic_vector to signed or unsigned. It allow more power to mix signed and unsigned operation inside 1 module. (Although as I know, signed and usigned are don't have difference with almost operating if you care about compensation bit).

As I know we have arithmetic (std_logic_arith) library for this convert, but someone said that it's not standard and conflict with numeric_std. You should switch to numeric_std with (for example, bit_length bit convertin):

```
result<=std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(128-x,bit_length); -- For unsigned          
result<=std_logic_vector(to_signed(128-x,bit_length); -- For signed
```